# How do you align a block item to the right edge of its parent (with CSS)?

Tags: css, alignment

I am aware that you can center a block item by setting the left and right margin to `auto`.

However, is it possible to align it to the right edge? And how would this be done?

Edit: *without* using `float: right` (because it doesn't seem to work, at least not with `<ul>`'s)

Edit again: Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<td style='vertical-align: top; text-align: center;'>
  <b>Choices:</b><br><br>
  <ul id='orderchoices' style='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>
    ...
  </ul>
</td>
```

Here is the style for `#orderchoices`

```
#orderchoices li {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background: #333 url(images/dark_gloss.png) repeat-x;
  color: #eee;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 160px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

I want the `ul` right-aligned in the `td`

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't seem to work'? The container's not properly enclosing the contents?

Comment: I mean it stays left-aligned.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">I'm the inner element!</div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    .outer { position:relative; }
    .inner { position:absolute; right:0px; }
</style>
```

If your inner element is positioned absolutely within a container that is positioned relatively, you can use `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` to indicate the inner element's distance from the edges of the parent container.

Make sense?

Comment: Sure and thanks for pointing this out. But what an ugly way to have to do it! I hope CSS4 has a better solution for this.

Comment: Hmmm. After giving it a try, it seems like the `position:absolute;` is causing the element to run off the edge of the page. (At the bottom)

Comment: I use this technique *regularly* - please update your question to include any relevant markup or CSS that's already being applied because something else is afoot, here :)

Answer (score 2):

To right align a block element to its parent try using float.
Remember to add an element after to clear the float so the bottom of the parent respects the bottom of the floated element.

```
    <div id="parent">
     <div style="float: right">
      <div>your stuff here</div>
     </div>
     <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

The 'position: absolute' method can also work, but when an element is positioned this way it is removed from the flow of html, thus its parent does not know the height of the absolute positioned element - hence the reason it might slip off the end of the page. You can overcome that by setting the height on parent but that of course relies on the fact that a) you know the height before hand, b) it won't change